# Sign extend a register to 64-bit (set all bits = sign bit) in Thumb mode

Tags: assembly, arm, twos-complement, sign-extension

I am using assembler for the ARM7TDMI (ARMv4T architecture). I'm using the Thumb mode because the ROM has a 16-bit bus (GBA). I want to sign-extend a 32-bit register to get another register with all bits set to a copy of bit 31 of the source register. The register to sign-extend is a high register, in particular R9.

I'm currently using this:

```
        mov     r0,r9
        mvn     r0,r0           @ sign bit needs to be inverted due to
                                @ the silly ARM carry convention
        add     r0,r0           @ copy sign bit to carry
        sbc     r0,r0           @ sign-extend R9
```

but that takes 4 instructions. Is there a shorter way?

Comment: Try `mov r1, r9; asrs r1, r1, #32`

Comment: @fuz: Note that you only need to shift by `#31`, so you can do the same thing on other ISAs where out-of-range shift counts work differently than ARM.  The original sign bit becomes the new LSB, and the other 31 bits are copies of it.

Comment: @fuz Oh my, I completely missed that instruction/variation. I'm still getting used to the Thumb instruction set as you can probably tell. I was under the impression that "every bit operation required a register". By the way, if that was an answer I'd aprove it. And yes, I'm more comfortable with 31.

Comment: You can always ask a compiler, e.g. `int64_t sext(int32_t x){ return x; }`. https://godbolt.org/z/EErn4sY5a compiles to `asrs    r1, r0, #31` / `bx      lr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an arithmetic right shift by 31 or 32 to copy the sign bit as `-1` or `0` into a new register:

```
mov r1, r9       @ move to a low register to be usable as an operand
asrs r0, r1, #31 @ generate -1 or 0 in R0 depending on sign of R1
```

Comment: The overall idea is good. The GNU assembler doesn't accept `asrs`, only `asr` (I'd say it's a pitfall of the assembler, because the instruction updates the flags). I don't need to waste a register, so I use `r0` instead of `r1`. Thanks!

Comment: @PedroGimeno Use `.syntax unified` to select the modern unified syntax.  I have selected an example with two different operands to `asrs` to highlight that you do not need an extra instruction to end up with both high and low words of the 64 bit value in low registers.

Comment: understand when you switch to unified syntax you are going to need to change your other assembly language code or it may break.  that or just use asr and be done with it.  the hardware thumb instruction sets the flags it is not an assembler thing.  after 15-20 years though the gnu folks could just fix this (or one of us could) so that for thumb for a target that doesnt support thumb2 to just allow sub or subs, asr or asrs, etc. and be done with it.

Comment: @old_timer So you want code to produce different effects depending on what CPU type is selected?   I can't possibly see how this could ever go wrong.

Comment: the non-unified-syntax language is there and has been wrong for what is it 20 years now? Why would it be any worse to fix it while continuing to support the brokenness for legacy support?  the unified syntax is a massive fail by arm (like another one or two things I could think of off hand without trying) and certainly is significantly worse to use with gas than not for hand written code.

Comment: YMMV, it is easiest to just know that the non-unified you leave the s off and you get the thumb instruction (and the disassembly correctly shows the flag affected version).  for non-thumb2 you want to not use unified syntax, for thumb2 extensions, with unified syntax and suffer the code bloat because it leans towards the larger instruction even if the smaller is available.

Comment: FWIW I mentioned the problem with `asrs` vs `asr` because in gas I can do e.g. `add` or `adds` by default in Thumb mode (generating the same opcode of course), so I found it weird that I could not use either.